# How to join two tables without any condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

For example I have two tables (temp tables). One of them contains only IDs, and the other contains real information. They have exactly the same row number.

```
#Table1
ID
14
15
16

#Table2
CarModel    Year
Ford        1996
Ferrari     2005
Toyota      2010
```

How can I join this two table in one (without any condition, just the result table has 3 columns, no matter in what order)? I need it for inserting the result for real table

```
Cars
ID   CarModel   Year
```

And this table doesn't use identity. There is an own mechanism of getting IDs for inserting.
I'm not able to change it.

So as a result I need a table like one of the following (ordering is NOT important):

```
#Table3
ID   CarModel    Year
14   Ford        1996
15   Ferrari     2005
16   Toyota      2010
```

or

```
#Table3
ID   CarModel    Year
16   Ford        1996
14   Toyota      2010
15   Ferrari     2005
```

P.S. I understand how to do this with CTE and row_number(), but I think there is more easier way to do this task. And may be this code will be used in MS SQL Server 2000, so I will be glad to look at other variants of the solutions.

Comment: `row_number()` would be the way to accomplish this. However, I would have to question WHY you would want a join on these two tables if they dont actually contain related data.

Comment: CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` seems the best way to me. For SQL Server 2000 you would need to simulate it with an `identity` column or triangular join or use cursors.

Comment: @Tejs Thank you for your answer. I need this joined date to insert into real (not temp) table. And I need my inserted rows have IDs, which I have got from a stored procedure. But I realy don't care about what concrete id will be in each row. All I need that they all will be from my "pool" Yes it's not the best schema, but it is and I have to work with it.

Comment: OMG, you should really not do that! There's no guarantee SQL Server will preserve any ordering. You can't just pick a random row and say "Hey, you'll have this ID for one query!".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a triangular join that would work in SQL Server 2000 per Martin Smith's comment:

```
-- Some test data:
declare @Table1 table (
    ID int primary key
)
insert into @Table1 select 14
insert into @Table1 select 15
insert into @Table1 select 16

declare @Table2 table (
    CarModel varchar(50) not null,
    [Year] smallint not null
)
insert into @Table2 select 'Ford', 1996
insert into @Table2 select 'Ferrari', 2005
insert into @Table2 select 'Toyota', 2010

-- Here's the actual query:
select Table1.ID, Table2.CarModel, Table2.[Year]
from (
        select ID, (select count(*) from @Table1 where ID < a.ID) as JoinPredicate
        from @Table1 as a
    ) as Table1
    join (
        select CarModel, [Year], (select count(*) from @Table2 where CarModel < a.CarModel or (CarModel = a.CarModel and [Year] < a.[Year])) as JoinPredicate
        from @Table2 as a
    ) as Table2 on Table1.JoinPredicate = Table2.JoinPredicate
```

Of course, this assumes that Table1.ID is unique and Table2.CarModel + Table2.Year is unique.

The performance considerations of triangular joins are discussed nicely here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Comment: Why the complex casting condition? And not `where CarModel < a.CarModel or (CarMoDel = a.CarModel and [Year] < a.[Year])` ?

Comment: The execution plan and statistics io are identical on my box. Anyway, it's up to the OP to make any changes to fit his code standards.

Comment: For a small table, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @ypercube, I've updated to use your more elegant version of JoinPredicate. Thanks.