# Perform INSERT INTO with WITH query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I found a query in this SO solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230675/1432033) and want to use it in one of my query I'm working on. Example query in solution is like this:

```
;with t1 as (
    select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn
    from table1 
),
t2 as (
    select col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn
    from table2
)
select col1,col2
from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Instead of running this query multiple times (*as I need to use the result of above query at multiple places*) I want to do something like below:

```
declare @tempTbl table (col1 int, col2 int)

insert into @tempTbl (col1, col2)
;with t1 as (
    select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn
    from table1 
),
t2 as (
    select col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn
    from table2
)
select col1,col2
from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

But that `;with` is causing trouble... Help Plz...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common table expressions go **before** the insert:

```
; with  t1 as 
        (
        ...
        )
,       t2 as 
        (
        ...
        )
insert  @tempTbl
        (col1, col2)
select  col1
,       col2
from    t1
full join
        t2
on      t1.rn = t2.rn
;
```