# Merge loop of SQL queries into one SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, symfony

I built a loop in PHP that makes 500 SQL queries but I would like to merge the 500 SQL queries into one and get the same return (the companies and the count of the users on each company)

**Example of PHP code**

```
$companies =  array();
foreach ($fortune500Service->listAll() as $c ){
  $count = $entityManager
  ->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select("count(u)")
  ->from("AppBundle\Entity\User","u")
  ->where("u.email LIKE :d")
  ->setParameter("d", "%@" . $c["Domain"])
  ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

  if ($count == 0) {
    continue;
  }

  $companies[] = array(
      "Domain" => $c["Domain"],
      "Company" => "{$c["Company"]} ({$count})",
  );
}
return $companies;
```

**Example of 2 SQL queries that I want to merge**

Query 1

```
SELECT 
  count(u0_.id) 
FROM 
  user u0_ 
WHERE 
  u0_.email LIKE '%@company1.com'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT 
  count(u0_.id)
FROM 
  user u0_ 
WHERE 
  u0_.email LIKE '%@company2.com'
```

I prefer a solution using createQueryBuilder http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder but I am happy also with an SQL native query.

Comment: Put all the `u0_.email LIKE '%@somecompany.com'` conditions into an array and join them with `OR`.

Comment: I am not sure but If I put all the `u0_.email LIKE '%@somecompany.com'` conditions into an array and join them with `OR`. The result that I will get is the number of users in any company. For example 4 users in total. I want this result: 2 Users Company1 and 2 Users Company2.

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230350/how-to-combine-results-of-two-queries-into-a-single-dataset

Comment: You could `UNION` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN u0_.email LIKE '%@company1.com' THEN 1 END) as First_cnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN u0_.email LIKE '%@company2.com' THEN 1 END) as First_cnt
FROM user u0_
```