# Inserting two images into database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert two images into my SQL Server 2012 database. Inserting one image works, but inserting two images does not work:

Inserting one image:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[PicturesCamera1] (Name, [OriginalBitmap]) 
                    SELECT ''' + @CameraPicture1 + ''', 
                BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk''' + @ImagePath + @CameraPicture1 + '.bmp' + ''', Single_Blob) as Pic'

                INSERT INTO #tmpBus 
                    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @resulttext = 'File not found. Picture seems not to be available on camera 1 cache any more.';
END CATCH
```

Inserting two images:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[PicturesCamera1] (Name, [OriginalBitmap], [PreviewJpg]) 
                SELECT ''' + @CameraPicture1 + ''', 
                BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk''' + @ImagePath + @CameraPicture1 + '.bmp' + ''', Single_Blob) as Pic,
                BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk''' + @ImagePath + @CameraPicture1 + '.jpg' + ''', Single_Blob) as Pic2'

    INSERT INTO #tmpBus 
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @resulttext = 'File not found. Picture seems not to be available on camera 1 cache any more.';
END CATCH
```

Comment: You missing a select for pic2

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230576/6305294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
INSERT INTO [PicturesCamera1] (Name, [OriginalBitmap], [PreviewJpg]) 
    SELECT
      '...', 
      (SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk '...', Single_Blob) q) Pic1,
      (SELECT BulkColumn FROM Openrowset(Bulk '...', Single_Blob) q) Pic2
```