# how to merge two queries result into a single table

Tags: mysql

I have two queries  which are giving two diff result and both the resultant table have one common column what i want to merge both of them and have one resultant table which have combined the common column into one column

here is my queries

```
    query1=  select b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,sum(a.netamount) as amount from syncbill a, ecustomer b where a.outlet=b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER and a.cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) and month(curdate())=month(a.billdate) group by a.OUTLET;


 query2=   select b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,sum(a.netamount) as amount from syncbill a, ecustomer b where a.outlet=b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER and a.cancelled<>'Y' and year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) group by a.OUTLET;
```

the first query is giving me result like this

[image: this is the result i am getting from query1]

My second query gives me result like

[[image: This is the result i am getting from querry2[2]]

now what i want is to merge these two queries to get result like this

[image: i want this kind of result]

i have tried union but its repeting the data and showing table of two column only.
please any one out there having knowledge in Mysql please guide me how can i achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine results of two queries into a single dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230350/how-to-combine-results-of-two-queries-into-a-single-dataset)

Comment: Why don't use single query with `JOIN`?

Comment: @Alexander i have already tried that approach but  by using union my outlets are comming in same column and data of query2 starts after the query one result is over

Comment: The headings in your output aren't helpful - amount1 appears to be current month figures and amount2 appears to be year to date? And do use explicit joins rather than implicit joins. And is there a column called outlet in syncbill?

Comment: @Alexander i am little poor in sql can you help me out with join query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run below query you will get both columns at a time

```
SELECT b.customerdescriptor AS outlet, 
       Sum(a.netamount)     AS currentYearAmount, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN Month(Curdate()) = Month(a.billdate) THEN a.netamount 
             ELSE 0 
           end)             AS CurrentMonth 
FROM   syncbill a, 
       ecustomer b 
WHERE  a.outlet = b.customeridentifier 
       AND a.cancelled <> 'Y' 
       AND Year(Curdate()) = Year(a.billdate) 
GROUP  BY a.outlet;
```

Comment: Please format your queries (as I have done for you) to make them easier to read.

Comment: @NandeshwarBagde thanx it worked,, i have a doubt that here i am heaving 3 outlets but in my db i have 30-40.. so there wil be no problem for that na?

Comment: @Nick I have formatted it using http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm it's a good website, I do recommend

Comment: @WhatsThePoint yeah that's not bad for a computer.

Comment: @dheerajkumar the query shouldn't be affected by the number of outlets.

Comment: Please use explicit JOINs not implicit (`,`)

Comment: This are good answer but it didn't give the explanation about that and still use `implicit join` and it's wrong to do nowadays..

Comment: You can use it for small amount of data, for large amount of data suggest to use join, anyhow your requirement is for sum so I don't think it bad idea to use implicit join.

Answer (score 1):

`Union` are what you need

```
select 
    b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,
    sum(a.netamount) as amount 
from 
    syncbill a 
    Inner Join ecustomer b on a.outlet = b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER
where 
    a.cancelled<>'Y' and 
    year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) and 
    month(curdate())=month(a.billdate) 
group by 
    a.OUTLET;

Union

select 
    b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,
    sum(a.netamount) as amount 
from 
    syncbill a, 
    Inner Join ecustomer b on a.outlet=b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER
where 
    a.cancelled<>'Y' and 
    year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) 
group by 
    a.OUTLET;
```

And do not use `Implicit Join` use `Comma`. That's not good `Join` and if you don't know how the `Join` work it will become messy in your result.

But for simplify you can try :

```
select 
    b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,
    sum(case when month(curdate())=month(a.billdate) then a.netamount else 0 end) as monthAmount,
    sum(case when year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) then a.netamount else 0 end) as yearAmount 
from 
    syncbill a 
    Inner Join ecustomer b on a.outlet = b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER
where 
    a.cancelled<>'Y' 
group by 
    a.OUTLET;
```

And i am suggesting not use `a` or `b` as alias table.. Why not giving alias like `sb` for `syncbill` and `ec` for `ecustomer`.. Will make it sense..

Comment: sure i will use sensible name only..thank you for your help

Comment: Great if this answer help you.. :)

Comment: can you please help me in merging  "select outlet, sum(netamount)    from syncbill    where cancelled<>'Y'    and billdate>= date(now())  group by outlet"  this query with the above query you have answered....it is giving same value but has diff condion of current date which is now but i want that value as amount 3...i am not good at sql so not able to do that

Comment: Just same.. Put this after yearAmount.. Sum(case when a.billdate >= date(now()) then a.netamount else 0 end) as amount3